# Pandas multiIndex is entirely copied to a dataframe slice

Tags: python, pandas

I think there is a conceptual bug in the way multiIndex is created on a dataframe slice. Consider the following code:

```
import cufflinks as cf
df=cf.datagen.lines(6,mode='abc')
df.columns = MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Iter1','a'), ('Iter1','b'),
                                     ('Iter2','c'), ('Iter2','d'),
                                     ('Iter3','e'), ('Iter3','f')])
df.head()
```

Which create a simple multiIndexed columned dataframe:

[image]

Slicing this data frame:

```
new_df = df[['Iter1','Iter2']].copy()
new_df.head()
```

[image]

So it seems like the data is presented ok, but behind the scenes the complete index is still there:

```
In [52]: new_df.columns
Out[52]:
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Iter1', u'Iter2', u'Iter3'], [u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd', u'e', u'f']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Which seems like a bug to me since now when trying to approach the last column in the sliced dataframe returns nothing:

```
In [54]:
last_col = new_df.columns.levels[0][-1]
new_df[last_col].head()

Out[54]:
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
2015-01-04
2015-01-05
```

I'm would like to pass to my function a couple of multi-columns by slicing my original dataframe but it seems like there is no way for me to approach those columns programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html) what is new functionality in `pandas 0.20.0`, you can also check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-shown-levels):

```
new_df.columns.remove_unused_levels()
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(23)
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Iter1','a'), ('Iter1','b'),
                                     ('Iter2','c'), ('Iter2','d'),
                                     ('Iter3','e'), ('Iter3','f')])
idx = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,6), columns=cols, index=idx)
print (df)
               Iter1               Iter2               Iter3          
                   a         b         c         d         e         f
2015-01-01  0.517298  0.946963  0.765460  0.282396  0.221045  0.686222
2015-01-02  0.167139  0.392442  0.618052  0.411930  0.002465  0.884032
2015-01-03  0.884948  0.300410  0.589582  0.978427  0.845094  0.065075
2015-01-04  0.294744  0.287934  0.822466  0.626183  0.110478  0.000529
2015-01-05  0.942166  0.141501  0.421597  0.346489  0.869785  0.428602
```

---

```
new_df = df[['Iter1','Iter2']].copy()
print (new_df)
               Iter1               Iter2          
                   a         b         c         d
2015-01-01  0.517298  0.946963  0.765460  0.282396
2015-01-02  0.167139  0.392442  0.618052  0.411930
2015-01-03  0.884948  0.300410  0.589582  0.978427
2015-01-04  0.294744  0.287934  0.822466  0.626183
2015-01-05  0.942166  0.141501  0.421597  0.346489

print (new_df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Iter1', 'Iter2', 'Iter3'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]])

print (new_df.columns.remove_unused_levels())
MultiIndex(levels=[['Iter1', 'Iter2'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]])

new_df.columns = new_df.columns.remove_unused_levels()

print (new_df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Iter1', 'Iter2'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: Thanks! Any reason it is not implemented for me behind the scene when I slice?

Comment: In my opinion it is new funcionality, so maybe later it will be implemented. Glad can help!

Comment: That's a good solution @jezrael. Upvote, did not know that function.